# CS circles Coding Exercise: 26 Letters

Tags: python, computer-science

This coding exercise is giving me a lot of trouble and I need help.

Here is the problem.

> Write a program which does the reverse of the example above: it should
>   take a character as input and output the corresponding number (between
>   1 and 26). Your program should only accept capital letters. As
>   error-checking, print invalid if the input is not a capital letter.

Here is what I have so far.

```
inp = input()

if (len(inp) > 1 or inp != inp.upper()):
    print("invalid input")

else:
    print(ord(inp)-ord("A")+1)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: Input:
@
Program executed without crashing.

Program output:
0                         --------------------when the @ symbol is entered it doesn't print invalid

Expected this correct output:

invalid

Result of grading: Your output is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified in the comment, the problem appears to be that the validation doesn't cover enough cases.

To check that the number you calculate is a valid upper-case character you could just check if it is between 1 and 26:

```
if 1 < ord(inp) - ord("A") + 1 < 26:
    print(ord(inp) - ord("A") + 1)
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

To add this to your current validation:

```
inp = input()

if (len(inp) > 1 or inp != inp.upper() or 
    ord(inp) - ord("A") + 1 < 1 or ord(inp) - ord("A") + 1 > 26):
    print("invalid input")

else:
    print(ord(inp)-ord("A")+1)
```

Comment: Hi @Harpoonfever if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

```py
letter = input()

if letter>='A' and letter<='Z':
   
   print(int(ord(letter))-64)

else:

   print('invalid')
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out.

Add whatever you want to test to the `test_data` list.

```
# take advantage of the string module to get a string of all upper-case characters
from string import ascii_uppercase # equiv of 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

test_data = ['z', 'AB', '', 10, None, "@", *ascii_uppercase] # some test data including all the upper-case characters

for item in test_data:
    string = str(item) # turn the item into type str
    length_is_one = len(string) == 1 # get the length
    if all((length_is_one, string in ascii_uppercase)): # if all these are true
        print(ascii_uppercase.index(item) + 1) # print the index of the letter + 1
    else:
        print(f'"{item}" is {INVALID}') # I modified the invalid output
```

OUTPUT:

```
"z" is invalid
"AB" is invalid
"" is invalid
"10" is invalid
"None" is invalid
"@" is invalid
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
```